# Filter does not work in Wherefore art thou exercise in Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am doing an exercise that is asking for:

---

Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument). Each property and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array.

---

I tried to create this by doing:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);

  arr = collection.filter(function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0;i < srcKeys;i++) {
      return obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) || obj[srcKeys[i]] ==  source[srcKeys[i]];
    }
  });

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}


whatIsInAName([
  { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, 
  { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
  { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

However this returns a blank array. I think maybe I do not have a full understanding of how the filter method functions.

One of the listed solutions is:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // "What's in a name? that which we call a rose
  // By any other name would smell as sweet.”
  // -- by William Shakespeare, Romeo and Juliet
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);

  // filter the collection
  return collection.filter(function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < srcKeys.length; i++) {
      if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) || obj[srcKeys[i]] !== source[srcKeys[i]]) {

        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  });
}

// test here
whatIsInAName([
  { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, 
  { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
  { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

Please try to explain thoroughly, to help a noob like me understand why what I did does not give the same output as the given answer :(

Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

First, in the for loop you are comparing i to the array instead of array.length.

```
for (var i = 0;i < srcKeys;i++) {
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0;i < srcKeys.length;i++) {
```

Second, your filter function is the inverse of the solution. The solution only returns true if the item has the key and the value matches the source. Your filter function returns true if the item doesn't contain the key or if it contains it and the item and source values are equal, which in this case is all of the items.

```
return obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) || obj[srcKeys[i]] ==  source[srcKeys[i]];
```

should be

```
return obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) && obj[srcKeys[i]] ==  source[srcKeys[i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how the filter function ([Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) works, you would find your mistakes (you had a typo also, writing **srcKeys** instead of **srcKeys.length**). On an array, when the filter function is called, its passed callback runs on every object of the array. **This callback has to return either true or false**. it is like a test for every object of the array. returning true means test passed and returning false means test failed.